# how to correctly append the items of a json to a list

Tags: python, json, list

Here is the code I have written:

```
with open('/file/to/json/FImageAnn.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    # print(d[0])

for index, element in enumerate(d):
#     print element[2]
    listt = []
    if element[2] == 'y':
        listt.append(1)
    elif element[2] == 'n':
        listt.append(0)

    xy = []    
    for i in listt:
        # groundtruth.append(i)
        xy.append(i)
```

In this code I open a JSON file which contains the result of my annotations of images. They are either 'y' or 'n'.

What I am trying to do is extract the 'y' and 'n' and convert them to 1 and 0. This I append to a list. When I print the list I get a result where the list contains only one element. Something like:

```
In [240]: listt
Out[240]: [0]
```

I was expecting something like:

```
Out [240]: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
```

This is when the JSON contains 11 'y' values and 1 'n' value.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to put in `listt` if `element[2]` is neither 'y' nor 'n'?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? Do you have any problem with the JSON part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put the list creation inside the for loop, so it's being re-created as an empty list each time, move it outside the for loop.

```
listt = []
for index, element in enumerate(d):
```

Comment: My goodness, I can't believe I was that silly. Thank you for pointing that out.